# How to get Column names from a SharePoint list?

Tags: .net, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I created a List and added three columns to it.  When I look at the list in my "List Settings" page, I see the three columns I created and some default ones as well (Title, Created By and Modified By).  When I view the Items in the list I just see the columns I created.

My issue is that when I try to get a list of columns for my list from code I get a whole slew of other ones that I don't see anywhere (Version, Attachments, Item Child Count, etc.)

Here is the code I am using to get this list:

```
        List<string> visFields = new List<string>();
        foreach (SPField field in myList.Fields)
        {
            if (!field.Hidden)
            {
                visFields.Add(field.Title);
            }
        }

        return visFields;
```

Is looking at the fields the wrong way to go about this?  How can I get the same list of columns that is displayed when you view the items in the list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to get the DefaultView for your list (SPList.DefaultView), then inspect the ViewFields element.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spview.viewfields.aspx